# how to replace this code in the version of mui x-data-grid

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mui-x-data-grid

```
import {
  GridColumnMenuContainer,
  GridFilterMenuItem,
  HideGridColMenuItem,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const CustomColumnMenu = (props) => {
    const {hideMenu, currentColumn, open} = props;

    return (
        <GridColumnMenuContainer
            hideMenu={hideMenu}
            currentColumn={currentColumn}
            open={open}
            >
            <GridFilterMenuItem onClick={hideMenu} column={currentColumn} />
            <HideGridColMenuItem onClick={hideMenu} column={currentColumn} />
        </GridColumnMenuContainer>
    )
}

export default CustomColumnMenu;
```